# Securely sharing files accross the network to ubuntu and linux users

Tags: windows, samba, file-sharing, ldap

I have an ubuntu 10.04 server that I want to share files to windows and ubuntu users.
I also want them to use the login/password provided by my ldap server.

Now, I am not sure about which path to go now (yay unix, so many ways of doing the same thing :D).

I want the users to have a private folder (Accessed only by the user), one group folder (full access to the entire group) and a general folder (for everyone on the network).

Now, back on my windows server days I used to have one big shared folder with permissions like this

```
---shared folder (all can see but not write to it)
------group1 folder (all can see but only group can get in, but not write on its root)
---------user1 folder (group can see, but not get in, only user with full access)
---------user2 folder
---------user3 folder
---------group1 group folder (group can see and write to it with full access)
---general folder (everyone can see and have full access to it)
```

repeat the same group1 folder structure for other groups.

Now, this was easily done in windows managing the users permitions. I am not sure how to replicate this functionality on ubuntu, for both my ubuntu and windows users.

Is that structure doable? Or should I simply go and make separate shares for everything? (one share per user, one per group, one general) Or am I missing some other way to do that?

I am not asking for a detailed how to for all this, but an idea on how to do it and which tools I should be looking at would be greatly appreciated. I dont mind having a GUI (web or not) or just using plain good terminal.

I intended to do this using samba+ldap (ldap server is already working just fine on another VM).

So any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it. Just follow these permissions and ownerships:

Inside of the folder **share**, you may have this folders:

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 2011-11-23 18:20 general
drwxr-xr-x  5 root group1 4096 2011-11-23 18:20 group1
```

Inside of **group1**:

```
drwx------ 2 user1 group1 4096 2011-11-23 18:20 user1
drwx------ 2 user2 group1 4096 2011-11-23 18:20 user2
drwx------ 2 user3 group1 4096 2011-11-23 18:20 user3
drwxrws--- 2 root group1 4096 2011-11-23 18:20 group1
```

You have to set the UMASK to 002 and pay attention to the sticky bit (chmod g+s) given to the group folder.

**user1**, **user2** and **user3** must be member of **group1**.

Let me know if it worked!

Regards

Comment: I will try that.
Is there anyway that users with group1 as a secondary group to be able to access the group folder too?
Boss may want access to all folders :)

Comment: Yes, every user with group1 as secondary group will have access to this folder. The sticky bit will take care of making all new files belong to group1. I will correct my post.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, the solution works, but I moved in a different way in my project so I forgot to come here and hit the button :)

Comment: Ok, im glad to see it worked!